# Java hashtable errors-- identifier expected and illegal start of type?

Tags: java, hashtable

This is supposed to be part of a simple interpreter with several keywords, which I made into different classes. The program is supposed to iterate over the ArrayList, tokenize the Strings and parse them into KEYWORD + instructions. I'm using a hashmap to map all these keywords to an interface which has classes, where the rest of the processing takes place. Currently testing out one of these keyword classes, but when I try to compile the compiler throws "identifier expected" and "illegal start of type" messages. The line throwing all the error messages is line 18. Where is the code going wonky? I can't tell since I've never used a HashTable before. Thanks for the help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringSplit
{
interface Directive //Map keywords to an interface
{
    public void execute (String line);
}
    abstract class endStatement implements Directive
    {
        public void execute(String line, HashMap DirectiveHash)
        {   
            System.out.print("TPL finished OK [" + " x lines processed]");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    private Map<String, Directive> DirectiveHash= new HashMap<String, Directive>();
    DirectiveHash.put("END", new endStatement());

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        List <String> myString= new ArrayList<String>();
        myString.add(new String("# A TPL HELLO WORLD PROGRAM"));
        myString.add(new String("STRING myString"));
        myString.add(new String("INTEGER myInt"));
        myString.add(new String("LET myString= \"HELLO WORLD\""));
        myString.add(new String("PRINTLN myString"));
        myString.add(new String("PRINTLN HELLO WORLD"));
        myString.add(new String("END"));


        for (String listString: myString)//iterate across arraylist
        {   
                String[] line = listString.split("[\\s+]",2);
                for(int i=0; i<line.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(line[i]);
                    Directive DirectiveHash=DirectiveHash.get(listString[0]);
                    DirectiveHash.execute(listString);

                }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the compile error? That's probably a good starting point.

Comment: OK, so it's line 18. Which line is line 18? (Yes, I can count. I'm only trying to point out that pasting your whole program when you already know what line is failing is somewhat counterproductive.)

Comment: I strongly suggest you use Java naming conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get past your current compiler error, you'll need to put the `DirectiveHash.put("END", new endStatement());` call inside a block of some kind.  If you want it in the instance initializer, try this:

{
     DirectiveHash.put("END", new endStatement());
 }

Comment: You have another error in that the `endStatement` class does not implement `public void execute (String line);` because you are defining it with an extra parameter.  You'll also not be able to instantiate an `abstract` class with `new endStatement()` because it's *abstract*.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable names should start with a lowercase character. DirectiveHash is used a variable name and class/interface names should start with an uppercase.

Comment: No, `DirectiveHash` is only a variable. `Directive` is the name of the interface.

Comment: And that still causes quite a few issues... my point 5 below.

Answer (score 2):

Your `DirectiveHash.put("END", new endStatement());` should be in some method. And since your class `endStatement` is abstract it cannot be initializd using `new`

Answer (score 1):

Several issues to be honest:

1. endStatement does not correctly implement Directive as the #execute method signatures 
   don't match.
2. You can't do the following as endStatement is abstract (can't be instantiated directly).

   ```
   DirectiveHash.put("END", new endStatement());
   ```
3. This can't be done outside of a block or method. you'd normally use a constructor:

   ```
   DirectiveHash.put("END", new endStatement());
   ```
4. You never actually initialise DirectiveHash in main. Note that it's an instance variable of the class and main is a static method. For main to use DirectiveHash, it must have an instance of class StringSplit to obtain it from.
5. The following line is a bit misleading as you're assigning and instance var name to be the same as the class name. Legal but hellishly confusing to read and a really bad idea. Actually, in this case, it's more troublesome as you've not instantiated your DirectoryHash in #main. So the ivar directoryHash (to spare confusion) is being set to be a Directive and our subsequent call to "DirectiveHash=DirectiveHash.get(...)" becomes broken as it implies calling Directive#get, which doesn't exist.

   ```
   Directive DirectiveHash=DirectiveHash.get(listString[0]);
   ```
6. The following line is invalid as "listString[0]" is not valid. You declared listString to be a String in your for() loop - not the array.

   ```
   Directive DirectiveHash=DirectiveHash.get(listString[0]);
   ```
7. Your capitalisation needs to be more rigourous... use Initial caps for classes and interfaces and lowercase initials for method names and vars.

Well, that was like one of those you're the compiler interviews. I see some have been posted already so sorry about that. May have missed some too...

You may need to read around some of these issues:

- Constructors
- Static methods versus instance methods
- Implementing interfaces
- Purpose/ usage of abstract classes

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to instantiate an abstract class. abstract classes cannot be instantiated using the `new` operator.

maybe you should extend the `endStatement` class (and also rename it to `EndStatement`) and provide a concrete implementation for it